# Do we have anaphoric macros of seq.el?

Tags: mapping, sequences

In dash.el, there are anaphoric macros (it saves to write "lambda":

```
(--map (* it 2) '(1 2))
```

instead of `(-map (lambda (it) (* it 2)) '(1 2))`)

`seq.el` is more generic, it works on strings and vectors too, but it doesn't include anaphoric macros (and doesn't intend to, AFAIK).

Are you aware of a library that implements them ?

Thanks.

**edit**: in the needs, wrote a couple of them: https://gitlab.com/emacs-stuff/anaphoric-seq